# Why if the selected start_date is in a month different of the selected end_date it appears always an error saying that the date format is invalid?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a edit page that shows the start_date and end_date fields. The fields are like:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="start_date">Start date</label>
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type='text' onkeydown="event.preventDefault()" name="start_date"
             value="{{!empty($c->start_date)? $c->start_date->format('d-m-y - H:i') : ''}}"
                   class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY"/>
                   <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="end_date">End date</label>
        <div class="input-group date" data-provide="datepicker">
            <input type='text' class="form-control"
                   value=" {{!empty($c->end_date) ? $c->end_date->format('d-m-y - H:i') : ''}}" name="end_date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY"/>
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then to validate is used:

```
'start_date' => 'nullable|date_format:"j-m-y - H:i"',
        'end_date' => 'nullable|date_format:"j-m-y - H:i"|after_or_equal:start_date',
```

Then to update is used:

```
$conference->start_date = (isset($request->start_date)) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('j-m-y - H:i', $request->start_date) : null;
$conference->end_date = (isset($request->end_date)) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('j-m-y - H:i', $request->end_date) : null;
```

**Issue:**

The update works if is inserted a start date and end_date on the same month.

But if the selected start_date is in a different month of the selected end_date it appears always an error saying that the date format is invalid.

Do you know why?

Comment: which version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Are you using a datepicker library? If so, which one? Would you also add the JS code you're using to initialise the datepicker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be a date formatting issue.

You have some inconsistencies in the date formats in the examples you provided...

You output in : `d-m-y - H:i`

You validate with : `j-m-y - H:i`

And you have not stated what format is being provided by the JS date picker!

You need to make sure the date formats are consistent across all elements of the applications within PHP and the Frontend JavaScript.
Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for help with the PHP date formatting. And https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp for JS dates, although I suspect that you will need to find the manual for the date picker you are using.

Comment: Thanks, so the validation should be like "'start_date' => 'nullable|date_format:"d-m-y - H:i"',
", to update like " $conference->start_date = (isset($request->start_date)) ? Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-y - H:i', $request->start_date) : null; 
" and the input like " <input type='text' onkeydown="event.preventDefault()" name="start_date" value="{{!empty($conference->start_date)
                ? $conference->start_date->format('d-m-y - H:i')
            : ''
        }}
                                "
                               class="form-control" placeholder="DD/MM/YYY"/>".

Comment: And in the datepicker "                    format: 'dd-mm-yy - hh:ii',
"?